# sample of standalone NPAPI adobeflash hosting application

Tags: flash, qt, qt4, npapi, qt3

Somebody can point me to opensource of sample of standalone NPAPI adobeflash hosting application?

Comment: Meaning that you want to emulate NPAPI to host a flash NPAPI plugin in your app?

Comment: yes, or maybe you known other way? i need cross-platform solution (linux and windows), that is why npapi nor activex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know of any projects that will already do this, but there are pieces of [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) that could be used to work towards this. You'll need a lot of understanding of how NPAPI works.  Basically, you'll need to create your own NPN_* functions that you can give to the flash npapi plugin (which could be based on the NPAPIHost project in FireBreath, which is intended to become just that, but is not finished) and then load the plugin the way the browser normally would.  You might need to create a fake "Window" NPObject and possibly others, which could be done using the JSAPI stuff in FireBreath.

In short, FireBreath doesn't do what you need, but has a lot of tools that could be expanded to do it. If you're willing to contribute the code back I'd be willing to give you some suggestions and help you when you get stuck; this works into a project I've been meaning to do for a long time (for testing plugins for FireBreath). Pop into the IRC room if you're interested.

If not, you might still be able to find some useful code in the FireBreath project to help you on your way.  Good luck!